# Excel - Vlookup on moving reference

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, vlookup

Thank you for taking the time to read this and maybe answer this for me.

I am currently referencing a cell within an array like so:

=INDEX('CampPerf Output'!$1:$1048576,9,55)

This data unfortunately can move up and down along the columns of the array. For example, sometimes it will not be Row 9, it will be on

=INDEX('CampPerf Output'!$1:$1048576,8,55)

=INDEX('CampPerf Output'!$1:$1048576,10,55)

=INDEX('CampPerf Output'!$1:$1048576,11,55)

You never know, because the data above it may be absent for this particular day's reporting (its call volume for lines of business in a call center setting. Some lines of business don't receive any calls that day.)

New data is *INSERTED*, but will always land in column BC (Column 55). New data is inserted to the left, pushing cells right. Since the data can move up and down, and the references of a vlookup move as new data is inserted, my question is this:

Can I combine my Index and a vlookup in a way that makes the lookup column absolute, no matter what is inserted or deleted.

Comment: is there a reference in another column or row that is in line with this data?

Comment: Basically, how is excel supposed to know which cell to look in?  There needs to be some logic, a corresponding value in another column, the first number, a certain number of rows down/up from a constant value, something other than "it is what it is".  Excel requires logic not guess.

Comment: Yes there was! 

Under Campaign name (The header of one of the columns) is the name of the campaigns. I am using, on another tab, the name of the campaign as the point of reference for a vlookup.The corresponding data for that compaign exists along the row next to that campaign name. (This is the limitation of the reports engine we are stuck using) The vlookup failed because of that moving reference problem. Your previous solution of using the ends of the table worked until I realized that not ever campaign will be listed ever day, meaning that absolute pointer might reference wrong data.

Comment: Here's what the previous vlookup looked like: =VLOOKUP('Conversion'!J1,'CampPerf_Output'!$BC$1:$BM$20,2,FALSE)

This would be what I used to reference the array, but only the second peice of information next to the reference name. I would then make it the 3rd column in the vlookup for the third column, and so on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use:

```
=VLOOKUP('Conversion'!J1,INDEX('CampPerf Output'!$1:$1048576,0,55):INDEX('CampPerf Output'!$1:$1048576,0,65),2,FALSE)
```

This mimics your vlookup you provided, it looks in the range `BC:BM`.  Vlookups can use full column references, the `0` in the second criterion includes all the rows.

Comment: Ah! I see. I tried something similar but I did not do it correctly! I thought there had to be a way but google-fu returned nothing related. Thanks again Scott, you saved the day!